# Uri Path getting a file list

Tags: android, kotlin

Android 11 / Api 30
Lets say I have a path to a user selected path (URI) on an Android devices, how would I go about walking through that directory and not the sub directories that might be deeper within it, for files with the extension .pref, so that those files could be loaded later.

I've already done code for walking a path with in my own applications directory, but cannot find how I would do that from a user selected path in shared/external storage.

Answer (score 0):

> Lets say I have a path to a user selected path (URI)

A `Uri` is not a filesystem path. For example, `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68510202/uri-path-getting-a-file-list` is a `Uri`.

> how would I go about walking through that directory

I am going to assume that you obtained the `Uri` via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree`.

> how would I go about walking through that directory and not the sub directories that might be deeper within it, for files with the extension .pref, so that those files could be loaded later

There is no requirement for content in a documents provider to have file extensions, so your approach will not work for all cases. But, you can wrap the `Uri` in a `DocumentFile` using `fromTreeUri()`, then call `listFiles()` on the `DocumentFile`:

```kotlin
val docRoot: DocumentFile? = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, uri)

val docPrefs: List<DocumentFile> = docRoot?.listFiles().orEmpty()
      .filterNot { it.isDirectory }
      .filter { it.name.orEmpty().endsWith(".pref") }

val docs: List<Uri> = docPrefs.map { it.uri }
```

Here, `docPrefs` is the list of non-directory children of your root that happen to have a display name that ends in `.pref`.

> so that those files could be loaded later

That will only work if you call `takePersistableUriPermission()` on the `Uri` that you got from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.

Comment: That's and excellent reply :) thank you, I've a lot to work on it would appear, your assumption is the correct one, registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree())

Comment: Java please....